# Override one attribute in Rails strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Is there a way I can override one attribute yet still use strong parameters in Rails? Such as in the following example, if I wanted to override the person's name every time, but also use the `person_params` method. There has to be a better way than manually setting `@person.name`, right?

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    @person.name = "ABC"
    @person.save
  end

  private

    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want to do is override the name to some other string, or format it before saving, you can just do:

```
@person = Person.new(person_params.merge!(name: 'ABC'))
```

If you want to do the create and merge in one line, simply do this:

```
def create
    @person = Person.create(person_params.merge!(name: 'ABC'))
end
```

Comment: Why would you ever code in another language than Ruby.

Comment: Aren't a lot of Ruby/Rails gigs in Florida!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something similar to this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Seems like you would form a hash of the params that you want. From the link:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  person: {
    name: 'Francesco',
    age:  22,
    role: 'admin'
  }
})

permitted = params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
permitted            # => {"name"=>"Francesco", "age"=>22}
permitted.class      # => ActionController::Parameters
permitted.permitted? # => true

Person.first.update!(permitted)
# => #<Person id: 1, name: "Francesco", age: 22, role: "user">
```